# Programmatically click on a CheckBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox

Is there a way to programmatically generate a click event on a CheckBox? I am looking for an equivalent to Button.PerformClick();

Comment: is changing the checked property as Jeff suggested not sufficient? Can you elaborate?

Comment: ASP.net or Windows Forms?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why do you need to simulate a click, doesn't this line of code fits your need?

```
myCheckBox.Checked = !myCheckBox.Checked;
```

If you need to execute logic when the state of the CheckBox changes, you should use `CheckedChanged` event instead of `Click`.

```
private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("You are in the CheckBox.CheckedChanged event.");
}
```

Comment: I posted this but the question says "click event". This won't generate a click event.

Comment: Maybe I will refactor the control and use the CheckedChanged event... whatever will be easier.

Comment: Could the OP explain why this was the answer chosen, when it does not actually answer the question, which is to fire off the onclick event?!

Comment: I extrapolated that OP didn't know about the CheckedChanged event. While not answering his specific question, it solve his root intent of being notified when a checkbox is changed programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

Those solutions above calls Checkbox.CheckedChanged event.

If you want to explicitly call Click event you can this:

```
checkBox1_Click(checkBox1, null);
```

Comment: This should have been the answer

Comment: This only calls the click event handler, it does not "generate" a click and does not change the checkbox value.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to generate a click event on the CheckBox?

If you want to toggle it's value:

```
theCheckBox.Checked = !theCheckBox.Checked;
```

If you want to trigger some functionality that is connected to the Click event, it's a better idea to move the code out from the `Click` event handler into a separate method that can be called from anywhere:

```
private void theCheckBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HandleCheckBoxClick((CheckBox)sender);
}

private void HandleCheckBoxClick(CheckBox sender)
{
    // do what is needed here
}
```

When you design your code like that, you can easily invoke the functionality from anywhere:

```
HandleCheckBoxClick(theCheckBox);
```

The same approach can (and perhaps should) be used for most control event handlers; move as much code as possible out from event handlers and into methods that are more reusable.

Comment: I am trying to tests a nasty Form, that enables some of the containing controls in the ..._Click event handler.

Comment: Just be careful - you don't want to call this method from theCheckBox_Click AND theCheckBox_CheckedChanged as it will be called twice when the check box is clicked.

Comment: @Grzenio: enabling/disabling controls in the `Click` even of a CheckBox is not a good idea; what if the `Checked` property is assigned by code? That does not trigger the `Click` event, and the UI will be in an inconsistent state. You should probably let that code be executed as a result of the `CheckedChanged` event instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still setting up a new workstation so I can't research this properly at the moment, but with [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) maybe it's possible that the checkbox supports the [IInvokeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.provider.iinvokeprovider.aspx) and you can use the [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.provider.iinvokeprovider.invoke.aspx) method?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can generate a click event in that way without calling the checkBox_Click event handler directly. But you can do this:

```
checkBox.Checked = !checkBox.Checked;
```

The CheckedChanged handler will still be called even if you do this.

Answer (score 0):

The `Button` `PerformClick()` method validates the active control, testing whether the active control can lose the current focus. There are two ways to possibly do the same thing for a `CheckBox`. Approach #1 is to use reflection to call the methods that are `internal` to the `Control` class:

```
public class CheckBoxPerformClick : CheckBox {

    private readonly static MethodInfo callValidateActiveControl;
    private readonly static PropertyInfo propValidationCancelled;

    static CheckBoxPerformClick() {
        try {       
            Type ty = typeof(Control);
            Type outBool = Type.GetType("System.Boolean&");
            callValidateActiveControl = ty.GetMethod("ValidateActiveControl", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new Type[] { outBool }, null);
            propValidationCancelled = ty.GetProperty("ValidationCancelled", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        } catch {}  
    }

    public CheckBoxPerformClick() : base() {
        this.Text = "Checkbox";
        this.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
    }

    public void PerformClick() {
        if (callValidateActiveControl != null && propValidationCancelled != null) {
            try {
                Object[] args = new Object[1];
                bool validate = (bool) callValidateActiveControl.Invoke(this, args);
                bool validatedControlAllowsFocusChange = (bool) args[0];
                if (validate || validatedControlAllowsFocusChange) {
                    bool cancelled = (bool) propValidationCancelled.GetValue(this);
                    if (!cancelled) {
                        ResetFlagsandPaint();
                        OnClick(EventArgs.Empty);
                    }
                }
            } catch {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Approach #2 tries to do the same thing, but without reflection:

```
public class CheckBoxPerformClick2 : CheckBox {

    public CheckBoxPerformClick2() : base() {
        this.Text = "Checkbox";
        this.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
    }

    public void PerformClick() {
        bool validate = CanPerformClick();
        if (validate) {
            ResetFlagsandPaint();
            OnClick(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    // before allowing a click, make sure this control can receive the focus, and that other controls don't require validation
    public bool CanPerformClick() { 
        if (!CanSelect)
            return false;

        Control c = this.Parent;
        while (c != null) {
            if (c is ContainerControl)
                break;
            c = c.Parent;
        }

        bool valid = true;
        if (c is ContainerControl) {
            var cc = (ContainerControl) c;
            valid = cc.Validate(true);
        }
        return valid;
    }
}
```